# Notification not updating correctly

Tags: android, service, notifications

I run a service, which is configured as foreground service via `startForeground(int id, Notification notification`), and I want to update this notification. My code to achieve this looks roughly as follows:

```
private void setForeground() {
    Notification foregroundNotification = this.getCurrentForegroundNotification();

    // Start service in foreground with notification

    this.startForeground(MyService.FOREGROUND_ID, foregroundNotification);
}

...

private void updateForegroundNotification() {
    Notification foregroundNotification = this.getCurrentForegroundNotification();

    // Update foreground notification

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(MyService.FOREGROUND_ID, foregroundNotification);
}
```

And to generate the notification depending on service state:

```
private Notification getCurrentForegroundNotification() {
    // Set up notification info

    String contentText = ...;

    // Build notification

    if (this.mUndeliveredCount > 0) {
        String contentTitleNew = ...;

        this.mNotificationBuilder
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_notify_active)
        .setContentTitle(contentTitleNew)
        .setContentText(contentText)
        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_stat_notify_new))
        .setNumber(this.mUndeliveredCount)
        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L)
        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
} else {
        this.mNotificationBuilder
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_notify_active)
        .setContentTitle(this.getText(R.string.service_notification_content_title_idle))
        .setContentText(contentText)
        .setLargeIcon(null)
        .setNumber(0)
        .setWhen(0)
        .setDefaults(0);
    }

    // Generate Intent

    Intent intentForMainActivity = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intentForMainActivity, 0);

    // Build notification and return

    this.mNotificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    Notification foregroundNotification = this.mNotificationBuilder.build();

    return foregroundNotification;
}
```

The problem is that my notification doesn't get updated correctly: When I start the service to run in the foreground, call `updateForegroundNotification()` several times with `this.mUndeliveredCount > 0` and after that again with `this.mUndeliveredCount == 0`, the small notification icon in the bottom right corner of the Notification won't disappear, even though no large icon has been provided. This behaviour is not exactly expected according to the [documentation of the `setSmallIcon(int icon)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setSmallIcon%28int,%20int%29) method of the `NotificationBuilder` class where it is stated the small icon should only appear in the bottom right corner if a large icon has been specified:

> `public Notification.Builder setSmallIcon (int icon)`
>
> Set the small icon resource, which will be used to represent the notification in the status bar. The platform template for the expanded view will draw this icon in the left, unless a large icon has also been specified, in which case the small icon will be moved to the right-hand side.

What am I doing wrong here updating the service notification? Or is this an Android bug?

Comment: The behaviour seems to be a bug; a workaround is provided below. The bug report at the official Android bug tracker can be accessed here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=59771&can=1&q=notification%20small%20icon&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having decided that it's not my wrongdoing here that leads to the unwanted small notification icon, I searched for and found a simple workaround for the aforementioned bug:

When updating the `Notification` via my `updateForegroundNotification()` method, I generate and update my notification ID with a "reset" notification. The "reset" notification is configured as follows:

```
this.mNotificationBuilder
    .setSmallIcon(0)
    .setContentTitle("Reset")
    .setContentText("Reset")
    .setLargeIcon(null)
    .setNumber(0)
    .setWhen(0)
    .setDefaults(0);
```

With such a notification, I call

```
Notification resetForegroundNotification = this.getResetForegroundNotification();

this.mNotificationManager.cancel(MyService.FOREGROUND_NOTIFICATION_ID);
this.mNotificationManager.notify(MyService.FOREGROUND_NOTIFICATION_ID, resetForegroundNotification);
```

before performing the intended notification update, and the unwanted bottom-right-corner-icon is gone in the next notification that sets only a small icon.

Comment: Was this all you did? I'm having the same issue and canceling it and notifying it doesn't solve it

Comment: Actually, that's all I did, but the APIs behaviour might have changed since then.